# Trying to get a variable from getchar() to keep it's value in a simple calculation program

Tags: c, printf, calculator, scanf, getchar

I'm learning C and I'm trying to create this program, that asks, in order, to enter an operator(+,-,*,%), a number then another number using scanf, printf and getchar(). When I do it asking the operator last it works, but I have to have it with the operator first.

Here is the code I've come up with that works (but is not in order):

```
char operator;
int numbers[2];
int result;

printf("Enter the first number:");
scanf("%9d", &numbers[0]);
printf("Enter the second number:");
scanf("%9d", &numbers[1]);
printf("Enter operation:");
getchar();
operator = getchar();
if (operator == '+') {
result = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
} 
else if (operator == '-') {
result = numbers[0] - numbers[1];
}
else if (operator == '*') {
result = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
}
else if (operator == '/') {
result = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
}
else {
result = 0;
}

printf("%d", result);
```

This is the code that doesn't:

```
printf("Enter operation:");
getchar();
char operator = getchar();
if (operator == '+') {
result = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
} 
else if (operator == '-') {
result = numbers[0] - numbers[1];
}
else if (operator == '*') {
result = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
}
else if (operator == '/') {
result = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
}
else {
result = 0;
}
printf("Enter the first number:");
scanf("%9d", &numbers[0]);
printf("Enter the second number:");
scanf("%9d", &numbers[1]);

printf("%d", result);
```

This one gives a random variable.

If the code wasn't in a block, forgive me, I followed the instructions as best I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of assignment operator is calculated "right at the moment": expression...

```
result = a + b;
```

... will not make `result` change its value when `a` or `b` change their values.

That's why your first snippet works as planned, and your second snippet shows garbage, as you first try to calculate the result of some binary operation on some garbage values (what `numbers` array elements store *before* they got assigned something useful), and only then try to get some input from user.

The key is `result` already has some value to this point, and this value won't change - unless you make a second assignment, of course. )

It's quite easy to fix this program: just separate the actual calculations from that input part. So that...

```
if (operator == '+') {
  result = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
} 
else if (operator == '-') {
  result = numbers[0] - numbers[1];
}
else if (operator == '*') {
  result = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
}
else if (operator == '/') {
  result = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
}
else {
  result = 0;
}
```

... will *follow* ALL the `printf/scanf` parts (except the one that prints the result, obviously). BTW, you can use `switch` for the same purpose:

```
switch(operator) {
  case '+':
    result = numbers[0] + numbers[1]; break;
  case '-':
    result = numbers[0] - numbers[1]; break;
  case '*':
    result = numbers[0] * numbers[1]; break;
  case '/':
    result = numbers[0] / numbers[1]; break;
  default:
    result = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I just want to know, what's a basic book on c that would have taught me that operations like that have to be done after the variable has the value? Is The C Programming Language basic enough? I have read some of it but I wonder will everything I need to know be taught since it states at the start it assumes some knowledge.

Comment: Well, K&R book by itself is a very solid base for studying - not only C language, but CS in general. You just need to give yourself some time to... digest it fully, may I say. ) The key is, as usual, practice and experiments - tinkering with your code, changing small parts of it to see what difference it would make is, in my opinion, the best way to learn CS.

Comment: As for the whole idea of variables storing relationships, and not values - well, you're definitely not alone in this: in fact, the whole paradigm named [reactive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) is built around it. )

Answer (score 2):

In the second part, you have not yet read the value of the 2 numbers, but you are doing operations on them.

Btw:

Instead of all

```
if (operation == '+') 
// etc
```

you could look in to the switch statement.

```
switch(operator) {
   case '+'
       number[0] + number[1];
       break;
   // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you have an extra call to `getchar()`

```
printf("Enter operation:");
getchar();
char operator = getchar();
```

should be

```
printf("Enter operation:");
char operator = getchar();
```

Otherwise you may miss the operator, and also you need to read the numbers first before doing the math.